# Laravel Passport + Laravel Socialite + Flutter

Tags: laravel, flutter, laravel-passport, laravel-socialite

I need your help.

I made an API with Laravel and an APP with FLutter.

Now I want to make google login.

In a browser or with a rest client like Insomnia, Postman or similar works fine. It is because the system shows me a google's page that I must write the email or google user that I want to logging in and, after, shows another page to write the password. Finally, all returns to APIS callback endpoint, showing the data (token and more).

But when I do it from my flutter app, the first google page where I need to indicate the user account, is send like string response (this string response is an HTML. I think is the HTML from google's page on we select or account).

How can I show this page and get the responses??

**NOTE:** flutter plugins like **flutter_inappbrowser** are not useful for me, because this plugins needs an URL and show it. I get the HTML on string when I use **flutter's http.get**.